# Flutter-clicking on signin button with firebase google authentication always signs in automatically without the option to sign in as a different user

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a signup/signin with google button on the main page and then when clicking, the user is given the option to put in the credentials for the google account. After signing in, the user is taken to a blank page with just a signout button where I call `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`

After the user clicks the signout button the user is taken back to the main page where they get the option to signin again.

The problem I have is once signed with a google account, even after clicking the signout button, the second time the user clicks on the signin button you are not given the option to sign in with a different google account, it automatically signs you in with the first account you signed in with. How do tackle this situation?

I have tried clearing the cache that runs when the user clicks on signout this way, but at this time it throws an error.

```
  Future<bool> signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    return true;
  }
```

Also I am not using any of the firebase cloud firestore features, i just brought it in for clearing the cache.Is there any way we make this happen without using cloud firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to `disconnect` the account before signing out:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

I asume you are using the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin.

Comment: This is what I meant about working with the google sign in account in my comment before. Also might try, _googleSignInAccount.clearAuthCache();

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the user from your Firebase Project. Try:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete();
```

You can then check manually that they have been deleted by looking at the entries on your Firebase Project under Authentication -> Users.

Comment: Hello Scott, I don't want to delete the user from the Firebase database, The user should persist in the database, but when that user signs out, the local cache should be cleared, so I get the option to sign in with a different Google account.

Comment: Hmm. I guess that won't work then. The only way I know to reauthenticate a user with a different account is to delete their first account from Firebase.

Comment: What about working with the google account login? Try GoogleSignInAccount  account = await googleSignIn.signInSilently(); account.clearAuthCache();

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you meant

Comment: Thanks Tarik for helping, Tariks answer worked out perfectly